# lxml How to keep multi string attribute after find()

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to parse xml file with namespaces.
XML file contain sql query and parameters like this:

`

```
<rs:data>
    <z:row Level='0' ParentName='Exam Workplaces' QueryID='7834' QueryName='EWWorksInQueueByPlaceID_v6' Body='--EWWorksInQueueByPlaceID_v6

declare
  @ExamWorkplaceID uniqueidentifier
 ,@SampleNum nvarchar(40)
 ,@PantheraPlatesCode nvarchar(20)
 ,@Locale int
 ,@ET nvarchar(MAX)
 ,@SDate DateTime
 ,@FDate DateTime


set @ExamWorkplaceID = :ExamWorkplaceID

...
**Too many strings skipped**
...


'
         Notes='V-Works in Queue By WorkplaceID' CursorLocation='3' CommandType='1' CursorType='3' LockType='3'>
        <Params ParamID='119448' QueryID='7834' ParamIndex='0' ParamName='ExamWorkplaceID' ParamType='72' ParamDirection='1'
             ParamSize='0'/>
        <Params ParamID='119453' QueryID='7834' ParamIndex='1' ParamName='SampleNum' ParamType='202' ParamDirection='1'
             ParamSize='40'/>
        <Params ParamID='119455' QueryID='7834' ParamIndex='2' ParamName='PantheraPlatesCode' ParamType='202' ParamDirection='1'
             ParamSize='20'/>   
    </z:row>
```

`My python code for getting sql body:`

```
from lxml import etree as ET

file = '02_Query_EWWorksInQueueByPlaceID_v6.xml'

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for a in root.findall('rs:data',root.nsmap):
    q = a.find('z:row',root.nsmap)
    body = q.attrib['Body']
```

`
After execute, I got one row string without \t and \n
Where did I make a mistake?

How to get sql body with keeped \n and \t

Comment: There is some thing called attribute value normalization that any XML parser does, to prevent that from happening you would need to use character references e.g. `&#9;` instead of literal characters (i.e. instead of the tab character). So basically you would need to fix the input creation.

Comment: Martin, thank you!
I get these files from the legacy code import mechanism.

I think it's easier to make an ascii parser for these files yourself. 
But I wanted to do it "correctly" by xml parsing.
Thank you for smart idea with symbols replace!

Comment: Well, the XML parser is doing the correct thing with attribute value normalization https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize, thus if you can't fix the input process to have any tab or newlines properly escaped as character references then indeed you will need to find some way around the improper input.

Comment: Martin, thank you!
Earlier I thought about creating my own parsing of these files.
You helped make this step!
Thank you! :)